# Can't run MySql Utilities

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-workbench

When I try and run MySQL Utilities from WorkBench I get the following error:

```
h3tr1ck$ mysqluc -e "help utilities"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/bin/mysqluc", line 23, in <module>
  from mysql.utilities.common.options import license_callback, UtilitiesParser
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mysql/utilities/common/options.py", line 34, in     <module>
from mysql.connector.conversion import MySQLConverter
ImportError: No module named connector.conversion
```

Then, if I type "mysql" into terminal it tells me that the command can not be found. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 23):

MYSQL Utilities assumes that the MySQL Connector for Python has been installed.
If you install it (http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/), MySQL Utilities should run OK.

Comment: Also the command "mysql" isn't found because you didn't add the directory it's in into your path. In my ~/.bash_profile file I added the line "PATH=/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH". I can't educate much about the PATH variable and shell usage here, but you need to learn this stuff if you intend to use the terminal.