# ImportError: No module named connector.conversion

Tags: mysql, macos, importerror

I'm very new to mySQL and just installed it on my Mac (OS 10.6.8). When I try to connect with the database through Terminal, I get this message:

> Last login: Tue Jun 17 10:42:23 on console mysqluc -e "help utilities"
>   GEdit-2:~ Eric$ mysqluc -e "help utilities" Traceback (most recent
>   call last):   File "/bin/mysqluc", line 23, in 
>       from mysql.utilities.common.options import license_callback, UtilitiesParser   File
>   "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/mysql/utilities/common/options.py",
>   line 35, in 
>       from mysql.connector.conversion import MySQLConverter ImportError: No module named connector.conversion

After reading in this and other forums, I installed:

```
mySQL-connector-python 1.2.2
```

I also added this path:

```
PATH=/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH
```

---

But, nothing has helped.

I have also tried to install:

mySQL-connector-odbc 5.3.2

but, the installation fails.

---

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Eric

Comment: Refer to:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24267017/importerror-no-module-named-connector-conversion

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't run MySql Utilities](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21781598/cant-run-mysql-utilities)

Answer (score 28):

From [Can't run MySql Utilities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21781598/cant-run-mysql-utilities):

> MYSQL Utilities assumes that the MySQL Connector for Python has been
>   installed. If you install it
>   (http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/), MySQL Utilities
>   should run OK.

Comment: I can confirm, installing MySQL Connector from this link solved the issue right away.

Answer (score 0):

I tried solving this for hours and ended up using the mysqldb library instead of mysql-connector for python. (Using Mac osSierra 10.12)
It was enough for my purposes though I can't ensure that it would be enough for everybodies purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Searching on Internet I met the solution. We have to install the library given by Python:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-mysql.connector
```

Or, if Python 2:

```
sudo apt-get install python-mysql.connector
```

Thanks to:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1014947/mysql-connector-python-importerror-no-module-named-mysql

Answer (score 0):

MySQL connector is required...but it seems this version is bugging out and not installing on Mac OS`mysql-connector-python-8.0.15-macos10.14.dmg`.

If someone is having the same problem, you can install [pymysql](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL) instead, as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16182294/installing-mysql-python-on-mac-os-x/25920020) suggests.